# How to identify numbers in low quality image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-enhancement

I need to convert the first image to the second image using python help with OpenCV. Please help me to do that!

**Sample Input**

[image: Sample Input]

**Sample Output**

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You got your answer, but still: you can address this problem with pure image manipulation e.g. do pixel by pixel manipulation in foor loop and if pixel value is anything not black, make it white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code -

```
import cv2  
img  = cv2.imread(r'image.png',1)  
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
cv2.imshow("Threshold",threshold)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

OUTPUT -

[image]